# Aligning images on webpage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a website with the effect of the bottom part of the 'hero' image is waved, from reading up this can be achieved by chopping the bottom of the image off, modifying it, and then displaying it after the first one.

The issue is that the footer of the image is not being displayed in the same scale/ratio as the main image and therefore looks off ([see here](https://imgur.com/a/xiXiiFG)).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 10000px;
}

.hero-image {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("../imgs/hero_image.jpeg");
  color: #000;
  min-height: 90vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.hero-image-footer {
  height: 100vh;
  /*min-height: 400px; */
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("../imgs/Untitled-1.jpg");
  /* background-color: aqua; */
  color: #000;
  /* min-height: 90vh; */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<header class="hero-image">
</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-transparent">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    Name here
                </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="hero-image-footer">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the ratio by the difference between the height of the main image and the remaining space? Or maybe using [`scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) to get the desired ratio?

Comment: @CcmU No, I will be honest and say I didn't know that the methods existed until you mentioned them.  I will need to read up on usage for them.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in comments, you can utilize the `calc` or `scale` function to get the desired behaviour.

The first one is a function that allow to do calculation between css values, so you can use it to perform calculation "by hand" and try to adjust your values to your desire. You can find out more in the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

The second one is a function that, and I quote from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale),

> defines a transformation that resizes an element on the 2D plane. Because the amount of scaling is defined by a vector, it can resize the horizontal and vertical dimensions at different scales.

Here is a little example of both functions:

```css
.calc {
  width: calc(100vw - 15em);
}
.scale {
  transform: scale(0.2);
}
```

```html
<h3>Default image:</h3>
<img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg">
<h3>Image with a width calculeted to be a 100vw - 15em:</h3>
<img class="calc" src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg">
<h3>Image with a transform equivalent to a 0.2 scale</h3>
<img class="scale" src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg">
```